# Does Gradient Boosting detect non-linear relationships?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent, boosting

I wish to train some data using the [the Gradient Boosting Regressor of Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn-ensemble-gradientboostingregressor).

My questions are:

1) Is the algorithm able to capture non-linear relationships? For example, in the case of y=x^2, y increases as x approaches negative infinity and positive infinity. What if the graph looks like y=sin(x)?

2) Is the algorithm able to detect interactions/relationships among the features? Specifically, should I add features that are the sums/differences of the raw features to the training set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GB method works by minimizing a loss function and by splitting each node in a fashion that produces high pure leaves. there is no population formula being estimated and therefore you can estimate all types of relations between the target and the features.
However I wouldn't put in the model correlated variables as:

> For gradient boosted trees, there's generally no strong need to check
>   for multicollinearity because of its robustness. But practically
>   speaking, you still should do some basic checks. For example, if you
>   discover that two variables are 100% the same, then of course there's
>   no point in keeping both. Even if it's 98% correlated, it's usually
>   okay to drop one variable without degrading the overall model.
>   Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-multicollinearity-a-problem-with-gradient-boosted-trees)